# sticking div on the top on scroll with css only

Tags: html, css

I have a div in middle of my page.I want to fix it on the top when it reaches the top after scrolling down my page.I want to do this using css only without javascript.

Comment: Not possible, CSS doesn't know a scrolling event.

Comment: You need jquery. Quite a simple one but impossible just with css

Comment: Not with pure CSS, jQuery is what you need.

Comment: Other than `position:sticky` ([**MDN link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)) which is not well supported of course.